# How to access a certain element in std::list<string>

Tags: c++, string, list

```
   list<string>&  whichList = theLists[ myhash( x, theLists.size( ) ) ];
```

I was wondering how to access a certain position say "i" and see if it was empty at that position.

I was doing it like this:

```
if(whichList[i] == 0)
```

but it does not seem to be working.

I realize this is wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot compare a `string` to `0`. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You can't index into an `std::list`, you're going to have to use iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to find the first list element whose value is the empty string is to use `std::find`:

```
std::list<std::string>::iterator it = std::find(whichList.begin(), whichlist.end(), "");
```

Its position can be computed (expensively) as `std::distance(whichList.begin(), it)`, but it is unlikely that you will need the actual numerical index, assuming that you have made a concious decision that `std::list` was the correct container type for your application.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like:

```
list<string> iterator it = whichList.begin();
std::advance(it, i);
if(*it == "") { /* ... */ }
```

But I think you need to clearly define what you mean by "empty" here - you can't compare strings to 0.

The key point is that `list` doesn't support random access - because of its implementation (a doubly-linked list), supporting random access would be an `O(n)` operation, i.e. linear in the length of the list in the worst case. That's inefficient, so it's deliberately not supported in the interface.

As others have pointed out, if you want random access then you're better off using something like a `vector` or `deque`. Generally speaking, you would use a `vector` if you only need fast insertion/removal at the end of the container, a `deque` if you also need fast insertion/removal at the front of the container, and a `list` only if you need fast insertion/removal in the middle of the container. In order to support the latter type of operation, `list` ends up sacrificing random access to elements.

See here for the definition of `advance`, incidentally:

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/advance.html

EDIT: As Alf pointed out, you can to some extent get fast insertion/removal in the middle of a vector using the gap buffer technique (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer), although an individual operation can be costly if you fill the gap (the idea is to amortise the cost over lots of operations, making an operation sequence comparatively cheap).

Comment: Uhm, not quite. A `list` supports (or was once meant to support) efficient splicing. You can do O(1) time insertion and removal in a contiguous array by just doing it a bit more intelligently than shifting elements, namely, the cursor gap technique, but you can't splice arrays in O(1) time. Unfortunately, as I recall the C++03 standard let each compiler decide on the `list` splice complexity, and than, if I recall correctly, in C++11 it was constrained to linear time. Removing the only in-principle efficiency advantage. Ouch. A remaining advantage is that a `list` doesn't invalidate so much.

Comment: @Alf: Thanks, I haven't come across the cursor gap technique to be honest, I'll go look it up! I've used lists for splicing in the past though, on the basis that it could be constant time and was guaranteed to be no worse than linear time. Shame that it's now linear time in C++11.

Comment: :) Both got there at the same time. Thanks though, quite interesting.

Comment: Well, re new edit, if you manage to fill the gap, then the buffer is full, and a new one larger one is needed. A `vector`-like gap buffer would do that like a `vector`, increasing the buffer size by some factor and moving or copying over to the new buffer. It's not an additional cost for the gap buffer, it's in general what happens (or what one would want to happen) when a buffer is filled completely. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `std::list` does not support random access lookup via `operator []`.  If you are going to continue to use a list, you should look at the  `std::advance` function.

```
list<string>::iterator itr = whichList.begin();
std::advance(itr, i);
if (itr->empty())
{
 /* ... assuming that you're testing for an empty string */
}
```

If possible, you might want to consider other standard containers, such as `std::vector` or `std::deque`, both of which provide random access lookup via `operator []`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a vector for this problem.

Comment: I think you should suggest a reason.

Comment: because he is reading a text file of strings. why would you use a list James?????

Comment: would if be easier to use a vector?